# xml file does not save after element has been added

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, ajax, xml

I am trying to create a chat system and i want that every time after the user wrote a massage and pressed the button, the computer will add a new element to an xml file. I have succeded at creating a new massage element and adding it to the xml file but the problem is that afer i stop the debugging and check the xml file, I see that it didn't saved.
Here is the HTML file

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true"              CodeFile="Chats.aspx.cs" Inherits="Chats" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function LoadXMLDoc(FileName) {
            var xmlhttp;
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.open("GET", FileName, false);
            xmlhttp.send();
            return xmlhttp.responseXML;
        }
    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <center>
        <h1> Chat </h1>
        <div id="Box" style="position:relative;height:200px;width:400px;border-width:2px;border-style:solid;border-color:black">
            <div id="Conversation">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                }
                function Chat() {
                    xmlDoc = LoadXMLDoc("Chats.xml");
                    newNode = xmlDoc.createElement("massage");
                    xmlDoc.documentElement.appendChild(newNode);
                    document.getElementById("Conversation").innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("massage").length;
                }
            </script>
            </div>
            <div id="Write" style="position:absolute; bottom:0;right:0;">
                <input type="text" id="MassageText" />
                <button id="SendMassageButton" causesvalidation="False" type="submit" onclick="Chat(); return false">Send</button>
            </div>
            </div>
    </center>
</asp:Content>
```

Here is the XML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<conversation>
  <massage>
    <from id="6">admin</from>
    <to id="7">blabla</to>
    <time>12/8/2014</time>
    <text>6 to 7</text>
  </massage>
  <massage>
    <from id="7">blabla</from>
    <to id="6">admin</to>
    <time>12/8/2014</time>
    <text>7 to 6</text>
  </massage>
  <massage>
    <from id="8">user1</from>
    <to id="7">blabla</to>
    <time>12/8/2014</time>
    <text>8 to 7</text>
  </massage>
</conversation>
```

I am sure that the element has been added to the XML file because I checked how many massages elements are exist after I have added the element and the answer was 4 instead of 3 which I actually have in the XML file.

Comment: Where is the code where you are saving the XML?  It looks like you are loading it and appending to it in the browser, but there is not a method of writing back to 'Chats.xml' - you will need to set up a way of handling the new XML on the server.  You need to write a request to the server to add these changes on the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

See here for saving document:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
 doc.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("item","urn:1"));
 doc.Save(Console.Out);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.save(v=vs.110).aspx